# Google Sign-in (Website) using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate the google sign-in button for my website by following this [article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) but my button does not show up on the website. Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the step before this. Instructions say to choose Credentials from the Console sidebar... but it isn't there. Edit: Nevermind. Sign-In is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a client ID on their platform and place it in the meta tag in 'content'.

Here you have the placeholder : "MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com".
To get a client ID you have to go here : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Although not specifically to the tutorial mentioned in the question, I show here a way to authenticate the google user via the google.appengine.api users module. Everything can be done without JavaScript, but functionalities specific to the website like getting a user ID can be done by setting up an encrypted cookie to check with JS after posting (if the problem is that, let me know, I'll add that too).

Note that this answer applies to Google App Engine applications running on Python2 and the Standard Environment. This app also uses jinja2 templating.

I am following the guestbook app available here for authenticating users with google accounts:

[App Engine Guestbook - authenticating users](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/authenticating-users)

For the HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Login Link -->
    <!-- <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div> -->
    <a href="{{ g_url | safe}}">{{ g_url_txt }}</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The Python backend set up (main.py):

```
import webapp2

# Templating
import jinja2
# Authenticating users with google's users API
from google.appengine.api import users

# GAP's db model (only shown to see how user is checked if a returning user)
from google.appengine.ext import db

# For the templating to work you'll need to set up a
# jinja environment linked to your own template directory, for example:
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
```

And the handlers (also on main.py):

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        template = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return template.render(params) # parameters can also be a dictionary!
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Login(Handler):
    def get(self):
        # If user chooses Google Sign-in
        user = users.get_current_user() # Returns google user if signed-in
        if user: # If google user exists...
            nickname = user.nickname()
            guser_id = user.user_id() # This is unique, email address may change.
            email = user.email()

            # Check if google user exists in database:
            u = User.by_google_id(guser_id)
            if u:
                # Do something to give rights to user on your website
                # e.g. via encrypted cookie.
            else:
                u = User(guser_id = guser_id,
                         email = email,
                         username = nickname)
                u.put()
            self.redirect("/welcome")

        else: # Otherwise render the google href that will direct the user to the sign-in process.
            g_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            g_url_txt = 'Login with Google'
            self.render("login.html", g_url=g_url, g_url_txt=g_url_txt)
            # After the user click on the link provided, sign-in will proceed, with succes, the
            # redirect back here, with "self.request.uri" and the get() will run again,
            # but this time with a google user.

class Welcome(Blog):
    def get(self):
        g_url = users.create_logout_url("/") # Will redirect to Login page if clicked on.
        g_url_txt = 'Logout'
        self.render('welcome.html', g_url=g_url, g_url_txt=g_url_txt)

class User(db.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    guser_id = db.StringProperty(required = False) # googleUser
    nickname = db.StringProperty(required = False) # googleUser

    # @decorator:
    # means that you can call the
    # object's method without instantiating the object
    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, uid):
        # 'cls' refers to the User class
        return cls.get_by_id(uid, parent = users_key())

    @classmethod
    def by_google_id(cls, gid):
        # 'cls' refers to the User class
        return cls.all().filter('guser_id =', gid).get()



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Login),
                               ('/welcome', Welcome)
                              ],
                              debug = True)
```

I hope this helps to you or someone else, I was stuck for days on this with no solution yet available, nor a clarification on whether the tutorial above has indeed been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Duncan, but having just tried the same tutorial page I did learn this: Google Sign-In has been deprecated and you should move to Google One Tap Sign Up and Automatic Sign In.
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview